# Контейнеризация темплейта aspnetcore-react

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core, docker

Недавно начал работать с реактом, решил попробовать реализовать SPA, воспользовавшись темплейтом aspnetcore-react.

Почитав документацию, узнал, что темплейты реакта и ангуляра не поддерживаются докером, поэтому решил попробовать запилить свое решение, для начала воспользовавшись сгенерированным в VS'17 докерфайлом:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
COPY ["SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj", "SpaProj.WebUI/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.Application/SpaProj.Application.csproj", "SpaProj.Application/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.Domain/SpaProj.Domain.csproj", "SpaProj.Domain/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.Persistence/SpaProj.Persistence.csproj", "SpaProj.Persistence/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SpaProj.WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "SpaProj.WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SpaProj.WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SpaProj.WebUI.dll"]
```

В итоге, само собой, не завелось. Описание ошибки:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.
```

Суть в том, что последние образы `dotnet` не содержат nodejs, по причинам абстрактной "производительности". Поэтому я пошел бороздить просторы интернета, в поисках решения. Я попробовал 2 варианта:

1. Качать nodejs прямо в образе.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS Base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 443
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build

# install node and npm
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.16.0
ENV NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA 2e2cddf805112bd0b5769290bf2d1bc4bdd55ee44327e826fa94c459835a9d9a
ENV NODE_DOWNLOAD_URL https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN wget "$NODE_DOWNLOAD_URL" -O nodejs.tar.gz \
    && echo "$NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA  nodejs.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xzf "nodejs.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && rm nodejs.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
# install npm packages first, this is slow so we want to minimise the number of un-cached runs
WORKDIR /src/SpaProj.WebUI/ClientApp/
COPY SpaProj.WebUI/ClientApp/package.json .
COPY SpaProj.WebUI/ClientApp/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix
# restore dotnet before build to allow it sit to cache
WORKDIR /
COPY ["SpaProj.Application/SpaProj.Application.csproj", "src/SpaProj.Application/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.Domain/SpaProj.Domain.csproj", "src/SpaProj.Domain/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.Persistence/SpaProj.Persistence.csproj", "src/SpaProj.Persistence/"]
COPY ["SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj", "src/SpaProj.WebUI/"]
RUN dotnet restore src/SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj
# copy source files and build
COPY . /src
RUN dotnet build /src/SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj --no-restore -c Release
RUN dotnet publish /src/SpaProj.WebUI/SpaProj.WebUI.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app
# Copy compiled app to runtime container
FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build /app .
CMD ["dotnet", "SpaProj.WebUI.dll"]
```

2. Пилить multistage и тащить nodejs из образа:

```
FROM 10.16.1-jessie as node-build
WORKDIR /src
COPY SpaProj.WebUI/ClientApp .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Ни одно из решений не помогло, исключение то же самое.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Какие могут быть решения?

Comment: А зачем вам нода в контейнере с аспнетом?

Comment: @tym32167, для получения зависимостей и сборки фронта. Я не сильно знаком с лучшими практиками контейнеризации такого рода приложений, иначе я бы не задавал такого вопроса :)
Как бы вы порекомендовали решить проблему?

Comment: я бы порекомендовал собирать все зависимости во время билда приложения, а в контейнер складывать уже собранный фронт рядом с уже собранным бекендом.

Comment: то есть по идее ваш контейнер должен только поддерживать asp.net core и всё

Comment: Ну, я использовал такой подход, когда собирал multistage (в п. 2). Собирал фронт из node-образа и клал его в final-образ через `COPY --from=node-build /src/build ./ClientApp/build`. Но, увы, это не помогло

Comment: Зачем собирать фронт в образе?

Comment: хотя я может чего не понимаю, вот есть [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918919/how-to-integrate-npm-install-into-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-build), [ишью на гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/155), [образ для билда](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/), [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: [похожая проблема на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/428107/)\

Comment: Увы, ни одна из этих ссылок для меня не нова. 
Ишью на гитхабе ссылается на образ, который вы линканули, который, в свою очередь в статусе Deprecated, и последняя поддерживаемая версия 2.0, а я использую 2.2 (хотя может это и не проблема вовсе?). Похожий вопрос, впрочем, как и докерфайл из поста на хабре я уже адаптировал и пробовал использовать в этом проекте, но увы, тщетно. SO/ruSO для меня как последняя надежда, куда я задаю вопросы, когда нигде в интернете ответов найти не могу :)

Comment: Я хотел бы чем то помочь, но мне самому походу надо эту тему ещё изучать и изучать, никогда не юзал контейнеризацию. Будем ждать кого-нить сведущего.